# Construct random variable from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I am trying to do this problem:

Suppose $ U$ is a random variable with distribution $\mathcal U(0,1)$. Find a function $g$ such that $g(U)$ has distribution:

i)$\mathcal E(1)$

ii) $Bi(5,\dfrac{1}{3})$

iii) a discrete random variable with range $R_X=(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and respective puntual probabilities $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

I have no idea how to solve this, is there a general method to construct a random variable from one that has uniform distribution? I would appreciate some help with the exercise. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a super standard method. Check your textbook, and to start off, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

Comment: In each case, the function $g$ is the inverse CDF (or quantile) function of the desired distribution.

Answer (score 2):

**Comment for (i).** The required function is $g(U) = -log_e(1 - U).$
The following R code uses the inverse CDF method to generate 10,000 realizations of $X \sim Exp(rate = 1),$ and then uses the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test to see whether the sample does indeed match
the desired distribution.

```
 x = -log(1-runif(10^4))
 ks.test(x, "pexp" ,1)

      One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

 data:  x 
 D = 0.0116, p-value = 0.1326     # P-val > .05 suggests agreement with Exp(1).
 alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

*Notes:* (a) The transformation $g(U) = -log(U)$ works as well
because $U \sim Unif(0,1)$ is equivalent to $1 - U \sim Unif(0,1).$
But the function I used is precisely the inverse of the CDF of
$Exp(1).\;$
(b) the K-S test would not work for discrete cases (ii) and (iii), but there are other GOF tests, which you may or may not be interested to investigate$\;$
(c) In simulation, pseudo-random generators usually supply
sequences of essentially independent observations from $Unif(0,1)$
and then some method such as the inverse transformation method
is used to sample from other distributions.$\;$ (d) Before (ii), you
might first try understanding the inverse CDF of some simpler distribution such as $Binom(2, 1/2).$

Graphs of the CDF and inverse CDF of $Binom(2, 1/2)$ are shown below.
In each case only the horizontal segments 'matter'.

[image]